# UICollectionView orientation change mishap?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

When my collection view is at the bottom and i change it from portrait to landscape, the cells disappear out the view, until I have to drag them down, like so:

REGULAR PORTRAIT VIEW:

[image]

VIEW WHEN ROTATED INTO LANDSCAPE:

[image]

DRAGGING CELLS FROM TOP OF VIEW:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: you need to set frame correctly.

Comment: which frame exactly? @AnkitKargathra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                             duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
 {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
    {
       self.collectionViewObj.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320);
    } 
    else
    {
       self.collectionViewObj.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
    }
}
```

Comment: after implementing the method and running the app, the initial portrait view is as expected, even after rotating into landscape it fixed the issue. However when I rotate back into portrait, the whole view gets distorted and I get the following error in the debugger: `Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.`